Access denied 403 Error while uploading to S3 bucket in production ECS Fargate (Working locally)
I am getting AccessDenied: Access Denied while upload files to my s3 bucket. But everything is working perfectly locally.
This is the error I am seeing in my cloudwatch
AccessDenied: Access Denied
api
at throwDefaultError (/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:838:20)
api
at /app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:847:5
api
at de_CommandError (/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:4748:14)
api
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
api
at async /app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/index.js:35:20
api
at async /app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/index.js:226:18
api
at async /app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/index.js:320:38
api
at async /app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-flexible-checksums/dist-cjs/index.js:174:18
api
at async /app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:98:20
api
at async /app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:121:14 {
api
'$fault': 'client',
api
'$metadata': {
api
httpStatusCode: 403,
api
requestId: 'Y9W345675765774JW',
api
extendedRequestId: 'LW2UXs3455646hiFZs0b/mU0UNisiXAfsdff43fdsgHOUH8s51OJklhRNU=',
api
cfId: undefined,
api
attempts: 1,
api
totalRetryDelay: 0
api
},

I also checked the permissions in IAM and I have given s3 full access. I thought there must be some issue with the env not being fetched properly so I logged everything. All the env are being fetched properly.

This is very important and will be useful to future developers who are stuck in this same situation.
Since I was using ECS Fargate, I had to add s3 permissions for ecsTaskRole.
This role is the one which you will be using while creating your task definition. "Task role" to be exact.
Go to IAM > Roles > Select "ecsTaskRole" (Create one if you haven't) > Permissions policies > Add required S3 permissions (I added AmazonS3FullAccess).
And it worked!

That's not actually correct. You need to add the permissions to the optional ECS Task Role, not the required Task Execution Role. The Task Execution Role is used by ECS to create your tasks. The Task Role is used by any code running inside your ECS task to access AWS services. If it worked for you, it is probably because you have the same IAM role assigned as both the Task Execution Role and the Task Role.

That's correct I have the same IAM role assigned to both of them. Thanks for the correction Mark.
